# How do I get plotly to show a grid of points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, plotly, points

I'm kind of new to programming and I'm trying to use Python (Jupyter Notebook) to create a simple plot using Plotly which has a bunch of points in a grid configuration.  In this example I'm just making a 5 x 5 grid of points.  I can do it successfully with Matplotlib, but not with Plotly.  How do I get Plotly to make the grid of points like with Matplotlib?  With Plotly it doesn't show all points.  I want to use Plotly because it's more interactive and I'm working on something separately where I'm trying to put a simple point grid plot like this in a Plotly dashboard.  Here's my code as it stands right now.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Set up sample data
posX = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
posY = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
posXX, posYY = np.meshgrid(posX, posY)

# Use Matplotlib
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(posXX, posYY, 'o', ms=5)
ax.set_xlabel('X Position')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Position')
ax.set_title('Point Grid');

# Now use Plotly
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = posXX, y = posYY, mode = 'markers'))
fig.update_layout(title = 'Point Grid',
                  xaxis_title = 'X Position',
                  yaxis_title = 'Y Position',
                  hovermode = 'x')
```

Comment: Your code can run and produce plots. Make sure that your notebook is opened with Classic Notebook (not Jupyter lab).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I can produce plots, but the one produced with Plotly is not what I expect.  I need it to show the grid of points, like the Matplotlib plot, but it just shows a single line of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code below can be used to create the grid in Plotly:

#### Sample code:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot

colours = ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple']

layout = {'title': 'Point Grid'}
traces = []

for x, y, c in zip(posXX.T, posYY.T, colours):
    traces.append({'x': x,
                   'y': y,
                   'mode': 'markers',
                   'marker': {'color': c,
                              'size': 10},
                   'name': c})

layout['xaxis'] = {'title': 'X Position'}
layout['yaxis'] = {'title': 'Y Position'}

iplot({'data': traces, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Output:

[image]

#### Comments:

I have intentionally used the lower-level Plotly code here, as (personally) I feel it provides a greater level of transparency as to what's going on under the surface of `graph_objects`, and provides easier configuration.

Regarding the issues you were having, this is because Plotly handles the `meshgrid` layout a bit differently from `matplotlib`. As such, I have used a very simple for loop and the `zip()` function in order to keep your existing dataset.

Comment: Thanks this worked nicely.  I think that for loop and the zip function were the key...I took what you did and used it in my original code and it worked....like so....

for x, y in zip(posXX, posYY):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers'))